# App crashing because of a function that sets layout managaer and adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm using android studio.

Please help if you know how to fix it.
Ok, so when I make the put data into recycler view function and call it the app  crashes (When I deleted it It worked perfectly fine so I'm 100 percent sure that the problem is within the putdataintorecyclerview function) with this error code:

```
    Process: com.example.watchitappthatworks, PID: 13438
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3e9
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6412)
        at com.example.watchitappthatworks.Adaptery.onBindViewHolder(Adaptery.java:54)
        at com.example.watchitappthatworks.Adaptery.onBindViewHolder(Adaptery.java:32)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2021-10-05 12:24:04.827 13438-13438/com.example.watchitappthatworks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

This is my main activity code
**Main activity**

```
package com.example.watchitappthatworks;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Movie> movieList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        movieList = new ArrayList<>();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://run.mocky.io/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        MovieApi movieApi = retrofit.create(MovieApi.class);

        Call<List<Movie>> call = movieApi.getMovies();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Movie>> call, Response<List<Movie>> response) {
                if (response.code() != 200){
                    //handle the error and display it
                    return;
                }
                List<Movie> movies = response.body();

                for (Movie movie : movies){
                    movieList.add(movie);
                }

                PutDataIntoRecyclerView(movieList);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Movie>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<Movie> movieList) {
        Adaptery adaptery = new Adaptery(this, movieList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptery);
    }
}
```

This is my **Adaptery** classcode

```
package com.example.watchitappthatworks;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class Adaptery extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptery.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Movie> moviesList;

    public Adaptery(Context mContext, List<Movie> moviesList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.id.setText(moviesList.get(position).getId());
        holder.title.setText(moviesList.get(position).getName());
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(moviesList.get(position).getImage())
                .into(holder.img);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title;
        TextView id;
        ImageView img;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idText);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }


}
```

This is my **Movie** class  code

```
package com.example.watchitappthatworks;

public class Movie {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String image;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is on this line, post the code from this function
Adaptery.onBindViewHolder(Adaptery.java:54)

Comment: I Edited it and added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
holder.id.setText(moviesList.get(position).getId());
```

This line is causing the crash, why are you trying to set the text using the integer id of a movie? Surely you want to use `getName()` instead.